# How to get custom label in page conversation via facebook graph api?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to get custom labels in page conversation via facebook graph api.
I found out from here. 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.11/conversation

But I can not find. 
I want to know, Can facebook graph api get custom label in page conversation?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately Facebook only gives you labels applied to a user. So first you need the conversation participants and their user-ids, then you can get the labels associated with that user.

#### To get all the custom labels on a page

`GET /v2.12/{page-id}/custom_labels` [(source)](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/custom_labels/)

#### Get the paticipants

`GET /v2.12/{page-id}/conversations?fields=participants`
[(source)](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.12/conversation)
You'll have to find which conversation you are looking for

or if you have the conversation id:  `GET /v2.12/{thread-id}?fields=participants`

#### Get the labels

The participant id is the user-id. You can use the user-id to get the labels here:

`GET /v2.12/{user-id}/custom_labels`
[(source)](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/custom_labels/)